# How to make Animations like in "Hollow Knight" Options

Tags: java, animation, graphics

I am making a game in java. I would like to achieve this effect:

[image]

How can I do this? I am not asking for code, but more for keywords, since I have really no clue on how to achieve this. Should I just do a normal animation with a sprite? The problem is that the result wouldn't be very smooth. Maybe there is another way (more efficient) to do it? 
Thanks (and sorry for the simple question)

Comment: I've looked at slow mo, and this looks like manually done frames. `The problem is that the result wouldn't be very smooth` I mean it *will* look smooth if you put sufficient amount of frames in it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an animated svg? Try out that tool, it can be helpful
https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/

Comment: Thanks guys :3 I guess I'll just make an animation. Thanks Jan, I'll give it a look later :)